# Ошибка в терминале при открытии файла python

Tags: python, консоль, visual-studio-code, powershell

***Здравствуйте. При попытке в терминале VScode открыть файл python "sieve.py" появляется ошибка красным цветом (скриншот во вложении). Команда sieve.py не найдена, однако существует в текущем расположении. По умолчанию оболочка Windows Shell не загружает команды из текущего расположения*
Помочь кто то сможет устранить проблему?** [image: ошибка]

Answer (score 0):

Один из вариантов должен сработать:

1.python3 sieve.py

2.python sieve.py

Может и сработать обе, если у вас установлены python 2 и 3 версии

Comment: Может так же сработать и **py sieve.py**. Зависит от того как питон записался в PATH системы

Comment: сработало  только py sieve.py. Спасибо за помощь!